# Ошибка при выводе данных из Struct

Tags: c++, qt

При сьемке фотографий от камеры, записываю имя файла (получается путь) и id в вектор.

```
void MainWindow::imageSaved(int id, const QString &fileName)
{
    Q_UNUSED(id);
    ImageData* image = new ImageData();
    image->iD = id;
    image->FileName = fileName;
    ImageDataPush(*image);

    isCapturingImage = false;
    if (applicationExiting)
        close();
}

void MainWindow::ImageDataPush(ImageData image){
    imageData.push_back(image);
}
```

сам верктор

```
#ifndef IMAGEDATA_H
#define IMAGEDATA_H
#include <QString>

struct ImageData
{
    int iD;
    QString FileName;
};


#endif // IMAGEDATA_H
```

далее, пытаюсь вывести информацию с помощью `qDebug()`
Информация показывается правильная, но сразу же после этого приложение вылетает.

```
void MainWindow::on_pB_Back_clicked()
{
    for(int i = 0; imageData.size(); i++){
        qDebug() << imageData[i].FileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Судя по представленному, `ImageData` - это просто структура, а не вектор. Как Вы применяете к нему `imageData.push_back(image);`? Вы куда-то спрятали (снова :-) ) объявление вектора из этих структур? И обозвали для "ясности" этот вектор так же, как и базовую структуру?

Comment: @Vladimir std::vector<ImageData> imageData; находится в классе MainWindow в public.

Comment: Т.е. я правильно догадался. К сожалению. А это хорошая практика - объявлять массив с тем же именем, что и его тип? В смысле, не сносит ли это крышу компилятору?.. (я не пробовал и теории в этом плане не знаю. Но меня такие конструкции несколько напрягают). Все, увидел - Вы одну буковку изменили на нижний регистр...

Comment: @Vladimir имя разное и другой мой вектор использует такую же констрокцию и работает прекрасно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пропустили в цикле в `void MainWindow::on_pB_Back_clicked()` условие:

```
for(int i = 0; imageData.size(); i++){
```

а предполагалось:

```
for(int i = 0; i < imageData.size(); i++){
```

Comment: да сам уже увидел, но все равно спасибо)